# Developing an app with Camera Access and GPS

Tags: gps, symbian, camera

I need to develop a symbian application in which the app is triggered while taking a photo and upload to a web location with the GPS location of the phone. I would like to know which all devices can support this and is there any API restrictions or licence required to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the relevant plug but what you are looking for is basically 3 chapters (Networking, Multimedia and Location Based Services) of the [Quick Recipes on Symbian OS](http://www.quickrecipesonsymbianos.com) book.

Since your application will use Networking APIs (and therefore cost the application user money), you will have to go through the [Symbian Signed](http://www.symbiansigned.com) process.

As far as how many Symbian-powered phones contain both a camera and a GPS, I am afraid you are going to need to look at the invidual handset manufacturers websites to come up with an exhaustive list. Outside Japan, they are [Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/matrix_gps_1.html), [Sony-Ericsson](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wportal/devworld/technology/symbian/phones?cc=gb&lc=en) and [Samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/prd/sym/product.list.do?platformId=1).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a list of Nokia models and their info](http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/matrix_s60_3ed_fp2_1.html)

[Here is a list of capabilities and what signing method they need](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Capabilities)